# Cross-compiler for OpenSPARC T1 platform?

Tags: compiler-construction, cross-compiling, sparc

I am working on an x86 processor that runs either Linux or Win7. I try to get some
standalone applications working on an OpenSPARC T1 platform. In the manual it says
the following:

"Make scripts are included to make it easy to recompile the C example programs. The make
MUST be run on a SPARC machine with SunStudio compilers."

It makes sense that I need the SunStudio compilers, but is it somehow possible to get this also working on an x86 machine? Or does the SunStudio compilers just work on SPARC architectures?

Many thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is available for Linux on x86 as well. Why don't you give it a try?